# Affixing Maple Paneling To Drywall

Tags: screws

Building a set of floor to ceiling bookshelves along a wall in the living room. Using 2 7/8 wide, 3/8 thick hard maple wainscot for the backing of the shelves. Pricier but looks so much better than plywood or particle board backing. I plan to use 1 1/4” wood or construction screws to attach a board to the wall studs every 16”. Question… should I affix the boards to the drywall so it doesn’t span 16” before being screwed to the wall? If so, what screws (drywall?) would you use? I want to be able to remove the entire unit if we move, hence the desire to use screws and not brads, epoxies, etc. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Attaching to the studs should be sufficient.

I would have a screw at the top and middle of each stud. I would also recommend using some longer screws. With ⅝" drywall you're only getting ¼" of penetration. With ½" drywall you'll get ⅜". I'd go with a 1⅝" screw, it'll secure things much better.

As far as screw type, I'd use a stainless fine thread. Fine thread screws have a higher tensile strength making them the *stronger* option.

Comment: The other idea I had was to run 1x2 or 1x3 furring boards horizontally and then screwing every other panel board into the furring strip. I plan on having rear support for the shelves screw into the wainscot, so using longer screws and going into the furring strip too might be a good idea for shelf support. Overkill??

Comment: I have several 7'x3' bookshelves and have them fastened directly to the studs and they're solid. My youngest boy is a wild one, climbs on everything and I don't worry about the shelves coming loose. With the thickness of your backing I would be perfectly fine securing them directly to the wall

Comment: @matt but it sounds like the OP plans to fasten the shelves to the wainscot, not to the studs.

Comment: @Huesmann My understanding is that he is building floor to ceiling bookshelves using a 3/8 maple for the backer board of the entire unit. Unless I misunderstood his question my answer remains the same.  Screw through the units backer board (*3/8 maple*) directly to the studs. This will sufficiently secure the unit.

Comment: Yeah...not clear if he's using the wainscot for backing the shelves, like attached to the shelves, or basically using it as wall paneling and building shelves with an open back.

Comment: I was assuming it would be one unit from the comment made in the question: (**I want to be able to remove the entire unit if we move**). I could be wrong though, wouldn't be the first time..

Comment: Was going to panel the wall and then build shelves with an open back. Span is 14’, so the design is to have 4 joists (6 counting sides) spanning the 14’ and to affix them to the ceiling and the paneling. The more I think about it, the more the horizontal furring boards make sense. If the paneling was horizontal, no problem… but with vertical paneling, and the fact that the joists won’t always line up with a stud, the furring boards make sense.

Comment: @user173624 How are you attaching the *joists* to the wall panel?